# Apache Spark driver memory

Tags: java, apache-spark

I've been trying to install and run a simple Java Apache Spark in intellij on windows but i have an error I can't solve. I have installed spark via maven. I get this error:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
19/03/20 23:53:23 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.0.0-cloudera1-SNAPSHOT
19/03/20 23:53:24 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
19/03/20 23:53:24 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: Drakker
19/03/20 23:53:24 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: Drakker
19/03/20 23:53:24 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
19/03/20 23:53:24 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
19/03/20 23:53:24 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(Drakker); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(Drakker); groups with modify permissions: Set()
19/03/20 23:53:25 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 50007.
19/03/20 23:53:25 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
19/03/20 23:53:25 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: System memory 259522560 must be at least 471859200. Please increase heap size using the --driver-memory option or spark.driver.memory in Spark configuration.
    at org.apache.spark.memory.UnifiedMemoryManager$.getMaxMemory(UnifiedMemoryManager.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.memory.UnifiedMemoryManager$.apply(UnifiedMemoryManager.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:308)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:260)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:429)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at Spark.App.main(App.java:16)
19/03/20 23:53:25 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: System memory 259522560 must be at least 471859200. Please increase heap size using the --driver-memory option or spark.driver.memory in Spark configuration.
    at org.apache.spark.memory.UnifiedMemoryManager$.getMaxMemory(UnifiedMemoryManager.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.memory.UnifiedMemoryManager$.apply(UnifiedMemoryManager.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:308)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:260)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:429)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at Spark.App.main(App.java:16)
```

I tried setting driver memory manually but it didn't work. I also tried installing spark locally but changing driver memory from command prompt didn't help.

This is the code:

```
package Spark;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark").setMaster("local");
//        conf.set("spark.driver.memory","471859200");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);


        List<Integer> data= Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
        JavaRDD<Integer> rdd=sc.parallelize(data);
        JavaRDD<Integer> list=rdd.map(s->s);
        int totalLines=list.reduce((a,b)->a+b);
        System.out.println(totalLines);
    }
}
```

I get the error when instantiating JavaSparkContext. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. It seems that you are trying to get started with Spark and... it seems you are not really going the right way :( as it seems you are mixing up some early Spark code with new Spark code and `Spark version 2.0.0-cloudera1-SNAPSHOT` does not look very good. May I advise to look at Java examples? Very selfishly, I'd recommend https://github.com/jgperrin/net.jgp.labs.spark or https://github.com/jgperrin/net.jgp.books.spark.ch01... Happy to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use eclipse, you can set `Run` > `Run Configurations...` > `Arguments` > `VM arguments and set max heap size like -Xmx512m.`

In idea you can set `Run\Debug Configurations`> `VM options : -Xmx512m`

In your code, you can try this `conf.set("spark.testing.memory", "2147480000")`

Answer (score 1):

I am a little confused by your code, as it mixes pre-Spark 2.x construct like `SparkConf` and a lot of RDD. It is not wrong to use them, but since Spark 2.x, things are a little bit different.

Here is an example using `SparkSession` and dataframes, which is a superset, more powerful, version of the RDD (to make things short).

In the example, you will see several ways to make your map/reduce operations, two with map/reduce and one with a simple SQL-like syntax.

## map and reduce with getAs()

```
int totalLines = df
    .map(
        (MapFunction<Row, Integer>) row -> row.<Integer>getAs("i"),
        Encoders.INT())
    .reduce((a, b) -> a + b);
System.out.println(totalLines);
```

## map and reduce with getInt()

```
totalLines = df
    .map(
        (MapFunction<Row, Integer>) row -> row.getInt(0),
        Encoders.INT())
    .reduce((a, b) -> a + b);
System.out.println(totalLines);
```

## SQL-like

This is probably the most popular one.

```
long totalLinesL = df.selectExpr("sum(*)").first().getLong(0);
System.out.println(totalLinesL);
```

## Full example

```
package net.jgp.books.spark.ch07.lab990_others;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.MapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.RowFactory;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;

/**
 * Simple ingestion followed by map and reduce operations.
 * 
 * @author jgp
 */
public class SelfIngestionApp {

  /**
   * main() is your entry point to the application.
   * 
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SelfIngestionApp app = new SelfIngestionApp();
    app.start();
  }

  /**
   * The processing code.
   */
  private void start() {
    // Creates a session on a local master
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
        .appName("Self ingestion")
        .master("local[*]")
        .getOrCreate();

    Dataset<Row> df = createDataframe(spark);
    df.show(false);

    // map and reduce with getAs()
    int totalLines = df
        .map(
            (MapFunction<Row, Integer>) row -> row.<Integer>getAs("i"),
            Encoders.INT())
        .reduce((a, b) -> a + b);
    System.out.println(totalLines);

    // map and reduce with getInt()
    totalLines = df
        .map(
            (MapFunction<Row, Integer>) row -> row.getInt(0),
            Encoders.INT())
        .reduce((a, b) -> a + b);
    System.out.println(totalLines);

    // SQL-like
    long totalLinesL = df.selectExpr("sum(*)").first().getLong(0);
    System.out.println(totalLinesL);
  }

  private static Dataset<Row> createDataframe(SparkSession spark) {
    StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] {
        DataTypes.createStructField(
            "i",
            DataTypes.IntegerType,
            false) });

    List<Integer> data =
        Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
    List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i : data) {
      rows.add(RowFactory.create(i));
    }

    return spark.createDataFrame(rows, schema);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Spark Session builder, and you can get spark context by spark.sparkContext()

```
public static SparkSession sparkSession(String master,
                                        String appName) {
return    SparkSession.builder().appName(appName)
                       .master(master)
                       .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", true)
                       .config("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", true)
                       .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "8g")
                       .config("spark.executor.memory", "8g")
                       .config("spark.executor.cores", "4")
                       .config("spark.cores.max", "6")
                       .config("spark.submit.deployMode", "client")
                       .config("spark.network.timeout", "3600s")
                       .config("spark.eventLog.enabled", true)
                       .getOrCreate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Driver Memory Exception`

This occurs when the Spark driver runs out of memory. That is when the application master that launches the driver exceeds the limit and terminates the yarn process.

> Error Msg: Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

**Solution: Increase your driver memory by setting up the below:**

```
    conf spark.driver.memory = <XY>g
```